# AngularJs+Jasmine How to test image.onload fires nested methods

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, angularjs-directive, jasmine

I have an angularjs directive. Image src is bound to `image.src` model. Directive watches `image.src` and must fire `resizeImage` controller's method when image is completely loaded.

I want to test `resizeImage` method is called, but I can not spy on it because of `image.onload` callback.

Besides, I've faced directive compiling issue again. I've solved it here [Can not get element in directive while testing AngularJs + Jasmine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32525123/can-not-get-element-in-directive-while-testing-angularjs-jasmine/32563805#32563805), but can not force work test for this new directive.

Here is html code:

```html
<form name="image-data" class="col-md-12">
    <textarea name="data-base64" class="form-control" rows="3" data-ng-model="image.src" placeholder="Add base64 encoded image string">    </textarea>
</form>
<div image-directive=""></div>
```

Here is directive code:

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .directive('imageDirective', imageDirective);

  function imageDirective ($log) {
    var imgController = function ($scope, $log) {
      $scope.image = {
        src: null
      };

      this.resizeImage = function (image) {
        $log.info('Runs resizeImage');
      };
    },

    link = function (scope, el, attrs, imgController) {
      var imageEl = document.getElementById('image');

      scope.$watch('image.src', function () {
        imageEl.onload = function () {
          $log.info('Runs image.onload');
          imgController.resizeImage(image);
        };
      });
    };

    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: link,
      templateUrl: 'dir.html',
      controller: imgController
    }
  }
```

Directive template:

```html
<div class="image-wrapper" data-ng-show="image.src.length > 0">
    <img data-ng-src="{{image.src}}" id="image" class="img-responsive" />
</div>
```

Spec code:

```js
describe('Directive with image onload event', function() {
  var $compile, $scope, $templateCache, $document, $log, template,
      html = '<div data-canvas-directive></div>',
      dirHtml = '<div class="image-wrapper" data-ng-show="image.src.length > 0"><img data-ng-src="{{image.src}}" id="image" class="img-responsive" /></div>';

  beforeEach(module('app'));

  beforeEach(inject(function(_$compile_, _$rootScope_, _$templateCache_, _$document_){
    $document = _$document_;
    $compile = _$compile_;
    $scope = _$rootScope_.$new();
    $templateCache = _$templateCache_;
    template = $templateCache.put('dir.html', dirHtml);
  }));

  var createDirective = function () {
    var elm = angular.element(html);

    $compile(elm)($scope);
    document.body.appendChild(elm[0]);
    $scope.$digest();

    return elm;
  };

  describe('when created', function () {
    it('should render the expected output', function () {
      var element = createDirective();

      expect(element.find('img').length).toBe(1);
      document.body.removeChild(element[0]);
    });

  });
});
```

Here is my plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/KPBtLw?p=preview.

Comment: So is your problem that you cannot spy on that particular method because you don't know how to access it or is it because you imageEl.onlaod never fires in your unit test?

Comment: @CalebWilliams imageEl.onlaod never fires

Comment: Have you fond any solution to this? I have stumbled on a similar issue, and I've yet to come across a viable answer.

Comment: @VladPintea have no solution still